# SQL Select: Do rows matching id all have the same column value

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
sub_id      reference
1           A
1           A
1           A
1           A
1           A
1           A
1           C
2           B
2           B
3           D
3           D
```

I want to make sure all the references in each group have the same reference.
Meaning, for example, all references in:

group `1` should be `A`

group `2` should be `B`

group `3` should be `D`

If they are not, then I would like to have returned a list of sub_id's.
So for the table above my result would be: `1`

Ideally, with these conditions reference would be in a separate table with sub_id as PK, but I need to fix first for a massive dataset before I can move on restructuring the database.

Comment: You need to use the GROUP BY clause in your SQL which you would need to review the syntax for what every DB you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following method:

```
select t.sub_id
from YourTable t
group by t.sub_id
having max(t.reference) <> min(t.reference)
```

Change `YourTable` to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for simple aggregation ?

```
select sub_id
from table t
group by sub_id
having count(distinct reference) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you want:

```
SELECT sub_id
FROM test_sub
GROUP BY sub_id HAVING count(DISTINCT reference) > 1
;
```

Here is what I used to test it:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_sub` (
  sub_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  reference varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_sub (sub_id, reference) VALUES
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'C'),
(2, 'B'),
(2, 'B'),
(3, 'D'),
(3, 'D'),
(3, 'D'),
(4, 'E'),
(4, 'E'),
(4, 'E'),
(5, 'F'),
(5, 'G')
;
```